# Can not Mock a final class in Java

Tags: java, testing, mockito, static-classes

I have a unit test, which looks like that:

```
DefaultCloudFoundryOperations cfOperationsMock = mock(DefaultCloudFoundryOperations.class);
        when(cfOperationsMock.getSpace()).thenReturn("development");
        when(cfOperationsMock.getOrganization()).thenReturn("cloud.foundry.cli");

        UserAdmin userAdminMock = mock(UserAdmin.class);
        when(cfOperationsMock.userAdmin()).thenReturn(userAdminMock);

        Mono<SpaceUsers> monoMock = (Mono<SpaceUsers>) mock(Mono.class);
        when(userAdminMock.listSpaceUsers(any())).thenReturn(monoMock);

        SpaceUsers spaceUsersMock = mock(SpaceUsers.class);
        when(monoMock.block()).thenReturn(spaceUsersMock);
        when(spaceUsersMock.getDevelopers())
            .thenReturn(Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four"));

        SpaceDevelopersProvider spaceDeveloperProvider = new SpaceDevelopersProvider(
            cfOperationsMock);

        String spaceDevelopers = spaceDeveloperProvider.getSpaceDevelopers();

        assertThat(spaceDevelopers, is(Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four")));
```

and a gradle dependency which looks like:

```
dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.0-jre'

    compile 'info.picocli:picocli:4.2.0'
    compile 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.26'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.5.2")
    testRuntime("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:1.5.2")
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.5.2')

    testImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2'
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+"


    compile 'io.swagger.parser.v3:swagger-parser:2.0.19'

    compile 'org.cloudfoundry:cloudfoundry-client-reactor:4.6.0.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.cloudfoundry:cloudfoundry-operations:4.6.0.RELEASE'}
```

When I try to execute this test, 
I receive:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: class org.cloudfoundry.operations.DefaultCloudFoundryOperations.
Can not mock final classes with the following settings :
 - explicit serialization (e.g. withSettings().serializable())
 - extra interfaces (e.g. withSettings().extraInterfaces(...))
```

Does anybody has an idea, how I can test it, or how should I adjust the code? 
I spend a lot of hours, but could not figure out a solution, which really works for me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In your production code (by opposition to your test code), instead of using `DefaultCloudFoundryOperations`, use the interface it implements: [`CloudFoundryOperations`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.cloudfoundry/cloudfoundry-operations/2.9.0.RELEASE/org/cloudfoundry/operations/CloudFoundryOperations.html)

For instance, declare like this:

```
public class SpaceDevelopersProvider {
  private final CloudFoundryOperations cfOps;
  public SpaceDevelopersProvider(CloudFoundryOperations cfOps) {
    this.cfOps = cfOps;
  }
  ...
}
```

Then, you can mock that interface.

```
CloudFoundryOperations cfOperationsMock = mock(CloudFoundryOperations.class);
...
SpaceDevelopersProvider spaceDeveloperProvider = new SpaceDevelopersProvider(cfOperationsMock);
```

Answer (score 0):

In runtime, when you using Mockito to mock an object, it will create a proxy class and extends the class that you want to mock. As in java, a final class cannot be extended, therefore mockito cannot mock final class.

Comment: So, how can I test that?

Comment: If you really want to mock it, you can consider to use PowerMock or PowerMockito instead. It can mock final / static classes / method. But i would not recommend because if you're doing right thing with your code structure, Mockito is enough for mocking and testing

Comment: I tried it, 
but still have some problems. 

How would the code look like and which dependency would be necessary?

Answer (score 0):

From the name of the class (`DefaultCloudFoundryOperations`) I would ***guess*** that first the class implements an interface, and second, that all consumers will take that interface, and not the concrete class.

If I ***would be*** right, you can mock the interface instead of the concrete class.

As said, this is a guess!